# square root of $(1-s)$ on complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

Considering the function $f(s) = \sqrt{1-s}$ on complex plane, given the branch cut $[1,\infty]$; I have no idea why the following is correct,
$$\lim_{r\to 0^+}f(5+ri) = -2i$$ 
Actually, I cannot understand why it is $-i$ and not $i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the circle centered at $1$ with radius $4$ (we will find this limit along this circle, rather than along a vertical line). We have $|f(s)| = 2$ for all $s$ on this circle, and specifically, $f(-3) = 2$. Note that every point along this circle is of the form $4e^{ix} + 1$ for some $x$. The branch cut makes $x \in (0, 2\pi)$. Now it's easy to see how to get $-2i$, because on this circle we have
$$
f(s) = f(4e^{ix} + 1) = \sqrt{1-(4e^{ix} + 1)} = \sqrt{-4e^{ix}} = \sqrt{4e^{i(x - \pi)}} =  2e^{i(x - \pi)/2}
$$
It's easy to check at $s = -3$ (which gives $x = \pi$) that we chose the right branch $-1 = e^{-i\pi}$ in the manipulations above. Now we can just let $x \to 0$, which gives $f(s) \to -2i$.

Comment: Perhaps I missed something, but $$\;2e^{i(x+\pi)/2}\xrightarrow[x\to0]{}2e^{i\pi/2}=2i\;$$ Where do you get, *in your expression*, the minus sign?

Comment: @DonAntonio I said it's easy to check in the vincinity of $s = -3$ that we have the right branch on $-1$. I didn't actually check, apparently, and it turned out to be wrong.

Comment: @Ar I see, but I think it may be simpler: using the given branch we cannot take the *positive* square root, as for example $\;\sqrt4=2\;$ would be on the cut, so we must take the negative ones. We still have problems with $\;[0,1]\;$ as for these values we get two possible results, yet for $\;-4i\;$ we already are on the circle of radius $\;2\;$ and we're then fine, and then $\;-4i=4e^{-i\pi}\;$ as the other option is on the cut...and we're done.

Comment: Thanks! perfect explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a graphical answer to this question:

[image]